# Magento 1.9.0.1 hunk #1 failed when installing SUPEE-8788 v2

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788v2

I'm trying to install SUPEE-8788 v2 on magento 1.9.0.1 and I get the error message

> patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
>
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED 
>   -- saving rejects to file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php.rej
>
> patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
>   patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
>   patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
>   patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
>   patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
>   can't find file to patch at input line 5810
>   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

I've tried to look up the curl.php.rej file, but it doesn't exist. I'm not even sure what the error message means, does the script fail at line 372, or does it fail to adjust something in curl.php at that line?

What can I do to solve this error?

I've installed all required previous patches for this version.

--edit--

I've installed 3941 and now the patch halts at another point.

> patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
>   can't find file to patch at input line 5810
>   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
>
> ### The text leading up to this was:
>
> |diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
>   |index 423902a..2c01684 100644
>   |--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
>
> ### |+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
>
> File to patch: 
>   Skip this patch? [y] 
>   Skipping patch.
>   1 out of 1 hunk ignored

There is no instance.js and no Parser.php. I've looked in the original 1.9.0.1 source as well and both files don't exist there, so I assume they should be created by the script. The script has enough rights to create files and folders, are there other things I can check?

---

New update

In the end I've applied certain parts of the patch manually to get it working. These were the step I had to take:

- install patch 3941 (1533 wasn't installed)
- remove the binary data from the patch so I could edit it in a editor
- added js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js manually
- added lib/unserialize from 1.9.3
- removed the swf's manually

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please check do you have Curl.php at path **downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/** ?

Comment: You probably deleted it or altered it, and it's not patching properly. Quickest way to do it, is restore it from a brand new install of 1.9.0.1 then try to patch again.

Comment: The file is there, I've uploaded the file from a cleanly downloaded 1.9.0.1, and applied the patch again, but the problem persists (same error). I'm reversing the patch with sh patch_name.sh -R and applying it with bash patch_name.sh.

Comment: I've included new information in the original post